# Xml parser not finding the attributes in XML layout

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to read from a web service that outputs results in to a web service in to an Xml parser. When i try to read the attributes, it is returning a -1 value. I was wondering if anyone could give me some help with why it is doing this. When I test the output from the file, the attribute output is null. However, it is finding the other tags such as response, list, etc..
thanks.

this is the xml file

```
 <response>
<list>
<category>(noun)</category>
<synonyms>hullo|hi|howdy|how-do-you-do|greeting|salutation</synonyms>
</list>
</response>
```

Comment: there are no attributes in that xml. You know, `<element attribute="attrValue" />`

Comment: I thought the attributes was: hullo|hi|howdy|how-do-you-do|greeting|salutation ?

Comment: it's the text of an element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parsing the XML like this:

```java
int eventType = parser.getEventType();
String name = null;
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        name = parser.getName();
    }
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        name = null;
    }
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT && name != null && name.equals("synonyms")) {

        // this is what you want, i guess
        String text = parser.getText();

    }
    eventType = parser.next();
}
```

Comment: the  if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT && name != null && name.equals("synonyms")) { says that it will always be false

Comment: @I'mback declare `String name` outside the `while` loop